# How to add a valid json string to an object

Tags: json, go

I currently have something like this

```
type Info struct {
    Ids        []string `json:"ids"`
    assignment string   `json:"assignment"`
}
```

Now my `assignment` is a large hardcoded json string that is read from a file.
I am doing something like this

```
r := Info{Ids: names, assignment: existingJsonString}
body, _ := json.Marshal(r)
```

However the above `body` is incorrect as assignment appears as string and not a json object.  How can I tell the info struct that `assignment` will be a json string and not a regular string so that `json.Marshal` plays well with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the type [json.RawMessage](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#RawMessage), and please note that `assignment` should be exported:

```golang
type Info struct {
    Ids        []string        `json:"ids"`
    Assignment json.RawMessage `json:"assignment"`
}
```

Example:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Info struct {
    Ids        []string        `json:"ids"`
    Assignment json.RawMessage `json:"assignment"`
}

func main() {
    r := Info{
        Ids:        []string{"id1", "id2"},
        Assignment: json.RawMessage(`{"a":1,"b":"str"}`),
    }
    body, err := json.Marshal(r)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", body)
}
```